# Server side or Clint side API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, server, client-server

If you're working with React.js, what is the best way to make an API call? For example, if I'm trying to get some book data from google books API should I do this on the client side with React.js or on the server side. Why would it be better to do it on one side vs the other? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on use case. Suppose if just want to list down books. Then why you need to handle this by server. But suppose e.g. if you want to bookmark some of those books on your side you can just either just store bookid or whole book info.

Comment: It depends. If it involves some processing, then do it on server else if it is only a display and without authentication thingy etc. then you can do it on client side.

Comment: If it is simple data and you first import it on server, in a way, it will be an overhead only.

Comment: @Revansiddh that makes sense thanks.

Comment: @Ahsen Yes, I think server side allows more freedom. Thanks.

Comment: @RockySingh of course. As I said it depends i.e. if you need that freedom then go for server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

app.use(
  '/api',
  proxy({
    target: 'http://api.books.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true,
    pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
  })
);

const index = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./build', 'index.html'), { encoding: 'utf-8' });

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.contentType('text/html').send(index);
});

const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  const host = server.address().address;
  const port = server.address().port;

  console.log('The server is running at http://%s:%s/', host, port);
});
```

And call like this (throw proxy), to not have problems with CORS or to replace server after.

```
fetch('/api/get-books')
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't need the code but is very helpful. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: that is the best practice to nicely connect with any external api :)
the code is to see its flow